# What is the correct regular expression in PERL for email validation?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I am a new user in stackOverflow. I have a query which is related with regular expression in PERL. I want to know the correct regex for the email. Example is also given below to create a regex.

for example,
 abc123@yahoo.co.in or
 abc345@gmail.com

Answer (score 11):

Email validation is really complex task so i recommend to use this code:

```
  use Email::Valid;
  print (Email::Valid->address('maurice@hevanet.com') ? 'yes' : 'no');
```